# Moved EJB to library, now EJB is not found

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

I have an EJB X implementing interface IX; I have a web service Z deploying in WebSphere; one of its classes declares the following:

@EJB
IX ix;

When X and IX were in the same source tree as the application, this worked fine.  I had it as @Singleton and @Startup, though I've sinced changed it to @Stateful.

The application has a jar it shares with another web service, and this 2nd web service can also make use of X.  So I want to move X to a jar (or whatever) used by each web service.

There is a jar currently used by both web services, so I moved X, IX and another dependent class to the source tree for that jar.  I compiled the jar and exported it, overwriting the jar previously used.  I've opened that and verified that the three new classes are in it.

When I run the app in the server (RAD/eclipse) I get an error message:

> com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface IX not present in application Z.

As stated above, I have this declared as @EJB in a class in the application, in a place that works when IX and its supporting classes are in the same source tree.

The RAD/eclipse project for the jar file did not originally have an EJB facet, so I added that; I recompiled and etc., get the same error.  I can add things to ejb-jar.xml if needed, though I thought that's what the Annotations were for.  But maybe there's something the annotations don't do, or that I need to add something for, now that the bean is in a different jar.

I figure I've missed something about configuring or declaring this.  Is this enough information to tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0):

EJB X must be in EJB jar, not utility jar for annotations to work. Put only interface IX in utility jar, and make all other projects - EJB, WS1 and WS2 - dependent on that jar (add jar to EAR/lib for example). Pack all projects in EAR.

Comment: will try it out tomorrow when I get to work -- thanks